# ocaml expression type unmatchings

Tags: loops, ocaml, println

I have the following loop:

```
let show expr =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | `S -> "S"^acc
    | `K -> "I"^acc
    | `I -> "I"^acc
    | `App(a,b) -> (loop acc a)^(loop acc b)
    | `B -> "B"^acc
    | `C -> "C"^acc
    | `Sprim -> "S'"^acc
    | `Bprim -> "B'"^acc
    | `Bstar -> "B*"^acc
    | `Cprim -> "C'"^acc
    | `Var(a) -> a^acc
    | `Con(a) -> a^acc
  in
  loop "" expr
```

And I have the following println function "I must use in this way";

```
let println x =
        printf "%s\n" (show x)
```

In order to print the following:

```
println (`App(`App(`App(`Bstar, `K), `K), `K));;
```

When I run it, I get the following error on `"printf "%s\n" (show x)"` line:

```
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b -> 'c)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type unit
```

Where is my mistake? How can I fix it?

I want to print the following value:

```
"B* K K K”
```

Comment: No enough context to reason your error.  Try making your problem self-contained but small enough so that ppl can read.

Comment: what else I am gonna write? I wrote whole the code.

Comment: Okay smartass, just downvote me. Because it seems like you don't have better thing to do, just you don't understand something, and you downvote it. This is your character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `show` to `println`:

```
println (`App(`App(`App(`Bstar, `K), `K), `K))
```

Also, `"I" ^ acc` should probably be `"K" ^ acc` for the K case.

Make sure that you are using `;;` to separate terms at the toplevel. If you have

```
let println x =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (show x)

println (`App(`App(`App(`Bstar, `K), `K), `K))
```

The `println` and `` (`App ...) `` will be considered arguments to the `printf`. Separate them like this:

```
let println x =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (show x)
;;

println (`App(`App(`App(`Bstar, `K), `K), `K))
```

Comment: I still get error. I am editing the question, and will put the error there.